# SOAP (Simple Object access Protocol) In LInux

Tags: linux, soap, ftp

How can we implement SOAP technology in Linux . ? I need to send data to FTP server and i need the acknowledgement? I am working on UBUNTU 12.04? can i use SOAP technology for this? How?

Answer (score 0):

SOAP is defined as followed:

> SOAP is a simple XML-based protocol to let applications exchange information over HTTP

Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/soap/